# calling render() after teardown() does not display list data

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I have list of menu options, and each menu item has it's own Ractive instance with different template but same shared data. When each selection is changed I am calling `teardown()` on rendered view instance and `render(domElement)` on current selection's Ractive instance.

An example Instance is like below, and all follow the same structure.

```
 var View = new Ractive({
      template: '#contacts',
      data: { 
          name: 'Contacts',
          contacts : dummyData // array data
      }
});
```

And I render them like below

```
  var isRendered = false;
  channel.subscribe("menu", function(msg) {
        if(msg === "contacts") {
                contentHolder.innerHTML = "";
            View.render(contentHolder);
            isRendered = true;
        } else {
            if(isRendered) {
                View.teardown();
                isRendered = false;
                console.log(View.get('contacts')); // Here I can see the data.
            }
        }
  });
```

In first `render()` call view is rendered as expected, but after calling `teardown()`, again if I call `render()` it does not render `contacts` list data and only displays name property, but was rendered on initial call.

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for reference, the question was answered on [GitHub](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1039)

`teardown()` is a non-reversible call that completely destroys the ractive instance. What you want is `detach()` function, which will remove the ractive instance from the DOM but not destroy it. You can use it later by calling `insert()`.